# Creating custom resource at runtime during application service calls

Tags: go, kubernetes, resources, operator-keyword

I have one .Net application running on K8 cluster which serves service requests. I had a requirement where I had to spin up pods when custom resource (CR) is available (which in turn have to be created during service call). I have implemented spinning up pod during runtime using operator pattern (GoLang) and its working fine. As of now I am applying custom resources manually. but this is not going to work in long run as I have to spin up N pods for N number of requests and have to apply N number of custom resources to achieve this. I am aware that, when end point is hit I can call K8's crud api s to create custom resource but not willing to touch our application code instead would like develop logic in custom operator codeline itself. but stuck as I have no idea how to achieve this? every input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try work queue to schedule/queue requests to perform jobs
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/coarse-parallel-processing-work-queue/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But queue is to process asynchronous service requests right? Our service calls are synchronous and I have to create custom resources (CRs) on demand. Sequence looks like this client sends request to create/delete agent, request hits our end point deployed in already running pod and from here I need to create/delete custom resource (on the fly) to be applied on operator (running in another pod) so that operator runs reconcile loop.